# Selecting rows with the multi highest date

Tags: mysql, database

I have some values in my table like this,

[Main Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VREkw.png)

I want to select only those with the latest/highest date,
The result will be like the picture in below:

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov8WP.png)

I already try with union but it didn't meet my expectations

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this - I suggest you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html and consider the examples there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the query to make the result like that

this my SQL query :

```
SELECT table1.jobno AS 'Job. No',  

(SELECT CONCAT(`search_date_1`, ' - ', `last_search_by_1`) FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM table1 WHERE jobno = table1.`jobno` AND search_by_1 != '')) AS 'Search Option 1',

(SELECT CONCAT(`search_date_2`, ' - ', `search_by_2`) FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 WHERE jobno = table1.`jobno` AND search_by_2 != '')) AS 'Search Option 2', 

(SELECT CONCAT(`search_date_3`, ' - ', `search_by_3`) FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 WHERE jobno = table1.`jobno` AND search_by_3 != '')) AS 'Search Option 3'

FROM `table1` AS table1 

GROUP BY table1.jobno
```

Answer (score 0):

Halo bro..

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE search_date_1 = (SELECT MAX(search_date_1) FROM your_table)
AND search_date_2 = (SELECT MAX(search_date_2) FROM your_table)
AND search_date_3 = (SELECT MAX(search_date_3) FROM your_table)
```

Please test this code, if it is correct please accept the answer.